# How can I specify input dimension in neural_tangent.stax framework?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a code defining structure of a model

```
from neural_tangents import stax
from neural_tangents.stax import Dense
from jax import jit

def model(
    W_std,
    b_std,
    width,
    depth,
    activation,
    parameterization
):
    """Construct fully connected NN model and infinite width NTK & NNGP kernel
       function.

    Args:
        W_std (float): Weight standard deviation.
        b_std (float): Bias standard deviation.
        width (int): Hidden layer width.
        depth (int): Number of hidden layers.
        activation (string): Activation function string, 'erf' or 'relu'.
        parameterization (string): Parameterization string, 'ntk' or 'standard'.

    Returns:
        `(init_fn, apply_fn, kernel_fn)`
    """
    act = activation_fn(activation)

    layers_list = [Dense(width, W_std, b_std, parameterization=parameterization)]

    def layer_block():
        return stax.serial(act(), Dense(width, W_std, b_std, parameterization=parameterization))

    for _ in range(depth-1):
        layers_list += [layer_block()]

    layers_list += [act(), Dense(1, W_std, b_std, parameterization=parameterization)]

    # print (f"---- layer list is {layers_list} ------")

    init_fn, apply_fn, kernel_fn = stax.serial(*layers_list)

    apply_fn = jit(apply_fn)

    return init_fn, apply_fn, kernel_fn
```

I can't see where I can establish dimension of input. By default it is 1, but I need to adapt this structure to inputs of higher dimension. `width` parameter in `Dense` specifies only output dimension. How can I change input dimension?
Code is from [here](https://github.com/bobby-he/bayesian-ntk)

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `Dense` doesn't require input dimension. It is specified in `init_fn` function:

```
init_fn, apply_fn, kernel_fn = model(
         W_std,
         b_std,
         width,
         depth,
         activation,
         parameterization
     )
_, init_params = init_fn(key, input.shape)
```